# Include CocoaPods in version control checkin?

Tags: ios, git, version-control, cocoapods

I want to know which files created by CocoaPods in a given iOS project should be checked into version control.  What makes most sense to include and ignore?  Should I just add the Podfile? Or should I add the entire pods directory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an ongoing debate even with the CocoaPods core team. https://github.com/CocoaPods/guides.cocoapods.org/issues/3

At some point someone felt that it should be ignored enough to get it into Github's gitignore [template for Objective-C](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore#L19-L20).

Some good points were brought up in the linked debate above about longevity of the project where if you check in your pods directory in the future other developers should always be able to build the source regardless of the state of CocoaPods or the specs repository without any dependency on the command line too. But I could see you having this same issues with Git submodules since the remote repositories could be deleted in the future as well. I think this comes down to your preference. Personally I don't like having updates to external dependencies directly in my source control history.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply @Keith.  The discussion you posted is helpful.  After reading it, I have decided that it make most sense to commit the Pods folder along with the Podfile.  The benefit of being able to checkout the project build without any additional setup seems paramount to me.  Leaving them out, as others have suggested, would leave other developers (and future versions of myself) at the mercy of all of the pods being available for download, while also requiring a CocoaPods install to get started.  That is not a risk that seems worth taking to me.

Comment: Apparently Podfile.lock is required to compile as well, so throw that in now.